# Removing logout/restart from mate session

Tags: ubuntu, mate-desktop, menu

So I have an Ubuntu bionic with mate desktop and I'm trying to remove the restart/logout options from the menu. At the moment I'm using the Brisk menu but could switch to anything else.

I already tried setting

- gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session suppress-logout-menuitem true
- gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session suppress-logout-restart-shutdown true
- gsettings set org.mate.screensaver logout-enabled false
- gsettings set org.mate.mate-menu.plugins.system_management show-logout false

but whenever I login, I still have the logout-option in the menu, not only in the Brisk menu, but any other too (mate, mate advanced...)

Moving/renaming gnome-session-quit and mate-session-save didn't help either.

This machine will be worked on via xrdp, and I want to prevent users from accidentally logging out since that messes up the service.

So anybody any idea?

Answer (score 0):

/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.mate.lockdown.gschema.xml holds the key

disable-log-out

Setting this with gsettings to false will still leave the correspondent menuitems, but clicking on them will not do anything.

```
gsettings org.mate.lockdown disable-log-out true
```

To logout you'll then have to find the process id of the session and explicitly kill it.